# javascript client-side return value to asp.net server-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, drag-and-drop

My javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // DETECT DRAG`n DROP TOOLS
    function dragndropMode() {
        //alert('drag here');
        if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

My Asp.Net control

```
<uc1:UC_MultipleFileUpload ID="UC_MultipleFileUpload1" runat="server" visible="CHANGE WITH JAVASCRIPT" />
```

How to change visible status of my Asp.Net control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visible` on ASP User Control is a server side attribute. If it's false, it will not render at all to your markup.

If you wan't to do this in client-side, you have to do something like this (requires jQuery):

```
<uc1:UC_MultipleFileUpload ID="UC_MultipleFileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // DETECT DRAG`n DROP TOOLS
    function dragndropMode() {
        //alert('drag here');
        if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      if(dragndropMode()){
          $("#<%=UC_MultipleFileUpload1.ClientID%>").hide();
      }
    });
</script>
```

This will add `display: none;` to the User Control and it will still appear in your markup.

Comment: great idea. worked. thank you very much @Henri-Hietala